# Search Option in Catalyst Framework

Tags: datatables, catalyst, template-toolkit

I have developed a web page for a database using catalyst and template toolkit. I have a table in my webpage. I want to have a search option in the same web page, which fetches data dynamically from the back end(database) and allows the user to search in the database.
I have jQuery datatables in my page, but it doesnot fetch the data from the database instead it will search in the table and give the result. As I am a new user to perl and catalyst, I request  to tell me how can I have a search option in my webpage.

If my question is not clear,I would explain in detail.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking is not trivial to achieve, but can be done.

You need to first have a good read of the documentation on DataTables regarding [server-side processing](http://www.datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/data_sources/server_side.html), and then rewrite the Catalyst Controller in your app that generates your data so that it mirrors the behaviour of Allan's PHP code: applying filters, sorts and limits, then returning JSON results. If you're using DBIx::Class and/or SQL::Abstract modules, it *should* be possible to create the equivalent functionality in far less code.

It's not for the faint-hearted, though. I've written and manage an application that uses Catalyst, TT and DT to render CRUD screens and I'm still not rushing to do a conversion to server-side processing until it proves *absolutely* necessary. (YAGNI principle + time-poor life.)